# How to change POSIXct objects display in facets title?

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

**I am trying to create a ggplot2 graph using facet_grid(). Each facet has to be entitled with a date (here a POSIXct object) and I would like to change the way it is displayed.**

How can i control the way POSIXct objects displays in ggplot2 facets title ?

Ex : this is how it is displayed : "2019-03-29"
and here is how I would like to see it written : "29/03/2018"

I have already looked at the labeller function but I can't figure out how to use it to change the way POSIXct object display. Maybe I am missing something.
I know facet labels can be "manually" changed but here I want a solution that works for any POSIXct object.

```
# create a dummy dataframe named ex
ex = structure(list(date = structure(c(1510531200, 1510531200, 1522195200, 
                                  1522195200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               cat = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), measure = c(0.0777420913800597, 
                                                        0.71574708330445, 0.725231731543317, 0.217509124660864)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                -4L), vars = "date", indices = list(0:1, 2:3), group_sizes = c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(date = structure(c(1510531200, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1522195200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = "date", indices = list(c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1L, 8L, 9L, 16L, 17L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), c(6L, 7L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 23L)), group_sizes = c(6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              12L, 6L), biggest_group_size = 12L, labels = structure(list(date = structure(c(1510531200, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1522195200, 1543881600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -3L), class = "data.frame", vars = "date"), drop = TRUE), drop = TRUE, class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# create a graph

plot_ex = ggplot(ex, aes(x = cat, y = measure)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(.~date)
print(plot_ex)
```

The facets are named "2017-11-13" and "2018-03-28". I want them to be "13/11/2017" and "28/03/2018".

Many thanks for your help,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change how dates are printed with `format`. Using that, we can set an appropriate labeller, without changing the data.frame column.

```
ggplot(ex, aes(x = cat, y = measure)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(.~date, labeller = function(x) format(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, I completely missed this "format()" option when I tested the code.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strftime`.

```
ex$date <- strftime(ex$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

library(ggplot2)
plot_ex <- ggplot(ex, aes(x=cat, y=measure)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(.~date)
print(plot_ex)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer works and is nice when you can modify the data outside the graph creation process. However, here I can not really do that (my bad I should have explained better in my post).

Comment: I think this method does not retain the sort order of the dates.